# Is Customer Service Agent and the Customer two different personas or different roles?

Tags: personas, user-journey, customer-experience, roles, journey-map

Are 'Personas' and 'Roles' different in every scenario?

Although i did my reading about roles and personas, im a bit confused about this topic with the context i'm working on.

Scenario - One day **Bruce**(Customer) finds out his water heater is broken and calls XYZ company to get it fixed. **John**(Customer service agent) receives the call and assigns **Bob**(Technician) for  to install a water heater.

John, Bruce and Bob are these 3 personas? or are they considered as 3 different user roles who interact with XYZ service?

Answer (score 1):

John, Bruce and Bob are both personas and represent 3 different roles.

Personas are fictional characters you create to assume a particular role that you want to represent during research for different user types.

If all of John, Bruce and Bob now exist in reality and in the same scenario, they are now users playing different roles when interacting with XYZ.